# Is it possible to check in my iOS App whether the iMessage Extension for it has been installed?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I would like to check, in my iOS app, whether the iMessage Extension for this same app has been installed, whenever my app starts up.  Then every N days I would like to remind the user to install the iMessage app in a custom popup alert.

I know that I can link to the iMessage app store directly like this:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/classic-mac/id1127542169?app=messages

But how can i detect whether the iMessage extension has already been installed or not on a user's device?    I only want to show the popup reminder if it is NOT currently installed.

I haven't been able to find any specific URL scheme for iMessage extensions that I could query against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with AppGroups!

From the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

> You can, however, enable data sharing. For example, you might want to
>   allow your app extension and its containing app to share a single
>   large set of data, such as prerendered assets.
>
> To enable data sharing, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable
>   app groups for the containing app and its contained app extensions.
>   Next, register the app group in the portal and specify the app group
>   to use in the containing app. To learn about working with app groups,
>   see Adding an App to an App Group.
>
> After you enable app groups, an app extension and its containing app
>   can both use the NSUserDefaults API to share access to user
>   preferences. To enable this sharing, use the initWithSuiteName: method
>   to instantiate a new NSUserDefaults object, passing in the identifier
>   of the shared group.

You could just flip a boolean in the shared NSUserDefaults to track install state for the extension.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using this solution.

Comment: How to flip is back when user remove or turn off in iMessage. You would think iMessage Extension is still installed?